# Is there a way to do competing risk regression where you can specify entry and exit?

Tags: r, regression

I would like to do competing risk regression with attained age as time scale. People enter the analyses at an age that is 5 years after their disease diagnosis and exit at the end of follow-up.

For regular Cox regression analyses, we use something like:

```r
coxph(Surv(time=entryage,time2=exitage,event=EventYesNo) ~ Treatment + Sex)
```

However, for competing risk regression, the `crr` function in the `cmprsk` package only allows an "ftime" variable, so I cannot incorporate both `entryage` and `exitage` into the model.

I already tried the crr function in two different ways:

1. ftime defined as exitage. However, persons are then in analyses from 0 to exitage and not from entryage to exitage.
2. ftime defined as exitage-entryage. However persons are then in analyses from e.g. 0-20 instead of 15-35.

Any idea how I can solve this?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just subtract `entryage` from `exitage` and use the resulting duration as your `ftime` variable?